# OpenVPN suddenly doesn't connect to my VPN anymore on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, connection, openvpn

No changes to settings or hardware. The VPN works fine in Windows 10 with the same settings. The VPN servers are up and responding to ping.

But when I right-click Network connections and choose my VPN, nothing happens. No connecting-icon, no error message, nothing. Just doesn't work, since about a few days.

I've tried adding and configuring the VPN again, no result.

However, the images in my VPN provider's installation guide is slightly different from what OpenVPN looks like now, which leads me to believe OpenVPN has been updated and options added that I have no idea what to do with.

Please advice.

Edit: connecting manually with `nmcli con up id [connection-name]` works fine. It would seem the OpenVPN GUI is not working, though. I can connect/disconnect the wired connection through the top bar icon, but nothing happens with the VPN connection still.

Comment: Try connecting using the command line in a terminal and update your question with any errors or warnings in the output.  The command is `nmcli con up id [connection-name]`

Comment: Excellent, that connected just fine. I still can't connect via the top bar icon, though. I can't disconnect the VPN from there either, unless I disconnect the wired connection altogether.

Comment: Interesting.  So now the question is, why is your VPN GUI interface broken?   I don't know how to troubleshoot that one.  I suggest adding this new information into your question.